# ::after doesn't seem to do what I'm expecting?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I may be misunderstanding the **::before** and **::after** features in CSS.

What I am trying to achieve, is a box of 200x200px, and then at the top right it would have another box (24x24). Here is what I've got:

https://jsfiddle.net/xd6L3h6v/

```
<div id="foo">bla test</div>

#foo {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
}
#foo::before {
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    background: red;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

However, this does not work. When I check it in *Firefox*, I don't see the **::before** part in *Firebug's DOM inspector*.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Firebug doesn't show the pseudo elements in DOM inspector. Chrome does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `content: '';`

```css
#foo {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}
#foo::before {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">bla test</div>
```

Comment: ARGH... now I feel stupid! Can't believe I missed that bit out. Its been one of those days :/ It won't let me accept this answer yet, but I will do as soon as it lets me.

Comment: no need to delete the question - it could help someone else who comes across the same issue in the future :)